# How To Change path using python script

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to write the python script by which I can change my pwd to /usr/local/src but the problem is this by using below script again I am redirecting to my prevoius directory

```
import os 
def path_init(): 
  print os.getcwd() 
  os.chdir("/usr/local/src") 
  print os.getcwd() 

def main(): 
  path_init() 

if __name__ == 'main':
    main()
```

output:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# python p.py 
/root/Desktop 
/usr/local/src 

[root@localhost Desktop]
```

Answer (score 3):

Impossible. Pwd is a per-process attribute and the script will always be executed as a separate process; it cannot change the shell's pwd.

(Except, that is, by useless hacks such as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# effectively a poor man's echo(1)
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

then

```
cd $(p.py)
```

.)